# Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 OpenGL games fullscreen slow

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, opengl

OpenGL games running in Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 in fullscreen mode very slow. FPS is very low (it lags). When I switch in the game settings in Windows Mode (same resolution 1680*1050) the game runs perfectly.

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460
Driver: NVIDIA 304.48 (I now use a beta driver, but in the older drivers the games are slower.)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your native screen resolution to whatever your window size was, fullscreen will/should be as performant as windowed.

*to clarify, game running at 1680x1050 windowed and fullscreen means your native resolution >= 1680x1050 ... probably*

If some random openGL app has to render a viewport, then scale it...performance is going to suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Unredirect Fullscreen Windows in CompizConfig Settings Manager:

http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-improve-gaming-performance-in.html

In my opinion it should be enabled by default.